# How to get a random number in one statement from a list of values;

Tags: java, random

Given the code below I have to find a way to get a random value from the values: 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280. The catch is that I have to write a single statement (One semi-colon) that will randomly pick one of the ints and assign it into the random_int variable. Does anyone have any idea how I could create a list or array of the numbers above and pick a random int from the numbers to assign to random_int in a single statement? Thank you for the help!

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
     int random_int;
    // Your single statement goes here
    System.out.println(“Number is: “ + random_int);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280);
        System.out.println(integerList.get(random.nextInt(integerList.size())));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Push them all into an array and random the array's index. All can be done in one single statement:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int random_int = new int[]{100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280}[random.nextInt(10)];
    System.out.println("Number is: " + random_int);
}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling?

Comment: I did, is there any problem?

Comment: what JDK, does not compile for me.  After your edit it is good.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Edited. Thank you all for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `Arrays` class to create a collection from your array

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280).
                                                          get(new Random().nextInt(10)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int random_int = new Random().nextInt(10)*20 + 100;
int random_int = (new Random().nextInt(10) + 5)*20;
```

`nextInt(10)` will give 0..9. (9 = (280 - 100)/20).

It is a matter of seeing the regularities in the desired numbers: steps of 20, starting with 100 upto 280.

*Could have been an exam question.*

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(getRandomNumber());
    }

    private static final List<Integer> NUMBERS = Arrays.asList(100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280);

    public static int getRandomNumber() {
        Collections.shuffle(NUMBERS);
        return NUMBERS.get(0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given below can be the single statement to do the job:

```
random_int = List.of(100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280)
                .get(random.nextInt(List.of(100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280).size()));
```

**Explanation:**

1. [`Random#nextInt(int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) returns an `int` value between `0` (inclusive) and `bound` (exclusive).
2. [`List#get(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) returns the element at the specified position in this list.
3. [`List#size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size--) returns the number of elements in this list.